# RANKX formula double counting sequential results

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data model has plans which have a one to many relationship with the asset fact table. All I want to do is give a ranking to the plan based on how many assets it has compared to the rest. Multiple plans are receiving the same ranking with different asset amounts, so i'm not sure what is going on here.

```
= CALCULATE(
  RANKX(
     ALL(arb_plans),
     [Total Assets]
 )
)
```

[image: Resulting Table]

**Edit: **

Okay the solution was to add the column name with the table in the all function. Not sure why that should make a difference.

```
= CALCULATE(
  RANKX(
     ALL(arb_plans[plan id]),
     [Total Assets]
 )
)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Without specifying a column name, `[Total Assests]` would be calculated per row of the table. With a column, `[Total Assests]` would be (should be) aggregated on that singular column value.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see more of your data model, but maybe try:

```
RANKX(
  DISTINCT('YourTable'[Plan ID]),
  [Total Assets]
)
```

Comment: If I use distinct every row is a 1 because i think the context is that row itself and there's only one planid.